# Resolve secret created with CDK in a Cfn L1 Construct

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-secrets-manager

How can I use an L2 [Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-secretsmanager.Secret.html) created with Secrets Manager to resolve as an L1 Cfn Property value?

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_secretsmanager as secretsmanager,
    aws_elasticache as elasticache
)
class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        redis_password = secretsmanager.Secret(
            self, "RedisPassword",
            description="Redis auth",
            generate_secret_string=secretsmanager.SecretStringGenerator(
                exclude_characters='/"@'
            )
        )
        self.redis = elasticache.CfnReplicationGroup(self, 'RedisCluster',
            auth_token=redis_password.secret_value,
            # other properties
        )
```

This gives the error

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Object of type @aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager.Secret is not convertible to @aws-cdk/core.CfnElement
```

In Cloudformation to resolve a secret I'd use something like

```yaml
AuthToken: !Sub '{{resolve:secretsmanager:${MySecret}::password}}'
```

But a L2 [Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-secretsmanager.Secret.html) doesn't output the Cfn Ref like L1 constructs do (that I know of)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I was only missing the [`to_string()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.SecretValue.html#towbrstringspan-classapi-icon-api-icon-experimental-titlethis-api-element-is-experimental-it-may-change-without-noticespan) method

```py
from aws_cdk import (
    core,
    aws_secretsmanager as secretsmanager,
    aws_elasticache as elasticache
)
class MyStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        redis_password = secretsmanager.Secret(
            self, "RedisPassword",
            description="Redis auth",
            generate_secret_string=secretsmanager.SecretStringGenerator(
                exclude_characters='/"@'
            )
        )
        self.redis = elasticache.CfnReplicationGroup(self, 'RedisCluster',
            auth_token=redis_password.secret_value.to_string(),
            # other properties
        )
```

This synthesizes to

```json
{
  "RedisPasswordED621C10": {
    "Type": "AWS::SecretsManager::Secret",
    "Properties": {
      "Description": "Redis auth",
      "GenerateSecretString": {
        "ExcludeCharacters": "/\"@"
      }
    },
    "Metadata": {
      "aws:cdk:path": "my-cdk-stack/RedisPassword/Resource"
    }
  },
  "RedisCluster": {
    "Type": "AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup",
    "Properties": {
      "ReplicationGroupDescription": "RedisGroup",
      "AtRestEncryptionEnabled": true,
      "AuthToken": {
        "Fn::Join": [
          "",
          [
            "{{resolve:secretsmanager:",
            {
              "Ref": "RedisPasswordED621C10"
            },
            ":SecretString:::}}"
          ]
        ]
      },
      "OtherProps": "..."
    }
  }
}
```